# Enceuntra un determinado objeto que contenga 'x' valor en el parametro name [mongoose]

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, objeto

Mongoose, mongoDB, express

Estoy atascado en una cosa y no consigo salir del bache. Me gustaría saber como puedo obtener todos los objetos que contengan "test" en el parámetro name, tras escribirlo en la URL. Lo hice así:

```
const { Router } = require('express');
const router = Router();
const companiesController = require('../controllers/companies.controller');

router.get('/', companiesController.getCompanies);
router.get('/:id', companiesController.getCompany);
router.get('/:name', companiesController.getCompanyByName);
router.post('/', companiesController.createCompany);

module.exports = router;
```

Y dentro del getCompanyByName:

```
companiesController.getCompanyByName = async (req, res) => {
    const companyName = await Company.find(req.query.name);
    res.send(companyName);
};
```

Si voy a la dirección `localhost:4000/api/companies?name=test` no me encuentra el objeto guardado en la DB que tiene ese valor test en el parámetro name.

Qué hago mal?

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas dos rutas van a chocar:

```
router.get('/:id', companiesController.getCompany);
router.get('/:name', companiesController.getCompanyByName);
```

Solo se va a resolver `:id`.

Para lograr lo que quieres puedes hacer lo siguiente.

```
router.get('/id/:id', companiesController.getCompany);
router.get('/name/:name', companiesController.getCompanyByName);
```

Y tu controlador quedaría asi:

```
companiesController.getCompanyByName = async (req, res) => {
    const companyName = await Company.find(req.params.name);
    res.send(companyName);
};
```

Para hacer esta consulta tu url quedaría así:

```
localhost:4000/api/companies/name/test
```

Si quisieras usar las query seria de esta manera:

```
router.get('/name', companiesController.getCompanyByName);
```

Este sería el controlador:

```
companiesController.getCompanyByName = async (req, res) => {
        const companyName = await Company.find(req.query.name);
        res.send(companyName);
    };
```

Y tu url quedaría mas parecida a lo que planteas:

`localhost:4000/api/companies/name?name=test`

## Error de query mongoose

Tienes un error en tu busqueda. La query debe especificar el campo en el que buscara:

```
await Company.find({elNombreDelCampoEnTuSchema:req.query.name});
```

Aun asi, para que esta busqueda funcione debes hacer una match exacto.

Para que busque solo una sección del texto debes usar regex de esta manera.

```
await Company.find({tuCampoEnElSchema: { $regex: req.query.name, $options: "i" }});
```

> Aunque esto tiene un coste de procesamiento más alto, para aplicaciones con menos de 10000 registros por colección no parece representar un gran problema.